# How to add a attachment in outlook programatically swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, outlook, url-scheme

I have opened the outlook app and send a file in it. I am able to open the outlook and set the To,Subject and Body but not sure how to attach file in the document directory 
The file is at path

```
  var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    let fileName = "supportdata.log"
    let logFilePath = (documentsDirectory as NSString).appendingPathComponent(fileName)

let scheme : String = "ms-outlook://compose?tosupport@tech.com&subject=Support data &body=Please find the attached file" 
     if let url = URL(string: scheme) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: {
            (success) in
            if (success)
            {
                print("Open \(scheme): \(success)")
            }                     
        })
    }
```

Comment: Refer this Link for Attach image in body : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44098422/4876245

Comment: You may attach a link/url of uploaded file to google drive as a remedy instead of file itself

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sadly, it is not possible.  There are two main issues:

1. You are deeplinking to an app, meaning sending an on-device message to another app that is effectively the same as a normal URI with a GET method parameterized string.  String only, no major data/files can be sent. The URL Scheme below is for reference. And it is the same as what you're using; though I think you are missing an '=' in your ms-outlook:// string.

   > `ms-outlook://compose?to=%@&subject=%@&body=%@`
2. iOS is pretty strict with app sandboxes, you cannot pass local files to other apps unless they are on the same app/file domain (e.g. you're the owner of both apps).  There are a few alternatives that work in a watered-down format, but are not relevant for this scenario.  Here's the thing, even if you could, Microsoft would need to support this file attachment feature, which it doesn't.  Sadly, there's nothing we can do about it on our side... other than asking Microsoft to add the feature.

However, if you want to do this in the apple mail app, that's certainly doable.

Comment: Is this answer still valid? I mean, is attachments still not support by Outlook App?

Comment: Is this answer still valid?

Comment: @seymatanoglu I cant say for sure, sorry :\ I haven't looked into it in a while.