# How to send email with attachments in iOS for outlook

Tags: ios, swift, email, outlook, openurl

I want to open MS Outlook app instead of native mail app in iOS. I am able to achieve this using recipient using : "ms-outlook://compose?to=(to)&subject=(subjectEncoded)"). How to attach files to the email in outlook using Swift.

I have referred to [How to open mail app from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981422/how-to-open-mail-app-from-swift) for sending email through outlook.

Comment: try adding multiple email addresses to  ```to``` with ```;``` in middle. (```a@gmail.com;b@gmail.com```)

Comment: @uditha - I tried that but did not work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46204740/how-to-add-a-attachment-in-outlook-programatically-swift-3