# Is there a way to use the "ms-outlook://" URI in iOS to open a specific email message by id?

Tags: ios, iphone, outlook, uri

I am attempting to create a QR code that opens a specific email message in the Outlook App for iOS.

I am specifically looking for something like:

```
ms-outlook://messages/view?id=1dfffe43-0d4e-4130-467e-08d5b4ee98bd
```

I have tried a lot of different combinations with no luck...

I am already aware of the "ms-outlook://compose" URI schema referenced here:
[URL Scheme Attachment Microsoft Outlook app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37304215/url-scheme-attachment-microsoft-outlook-app#)

I have already successfully pulled this off with trello, workfront, and zendesk. Just want to add outlook to the list.

Examples I have working with other apps:

Trello:

```
trello://x-callback-url/showCard?shortlink=h836Wd8k
```

Zendesk:

```
zendesk://agent/tickets/35436
```

Workfront:

```
workfront://TASK?ID=564f71b200d4b8f4a393335ed5a816c1
```

**Any help is appreciated!**

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?